# ECharts: Center moves in graph with scaleLimit

Tags: vuejs3, echarts

I am using Apache ECharts with a series of type 'graph' in my Vue3 project.

If I try to zoom out (further than my scaleLimit), then nothing happens. So far so good.
The problem happens, if you click on a different category in the legend.
I found out, that the center changes, even if my zoom stays the same, which makes the graph jump around on legendSelectChanged!

It is reproducible in one of ECharts examples: [ECharts Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graph-label-overlap)

Zoom out (or in, it doesn't really matter) completely and then some more(!!). The zoom will stop at the scaleLimit, which is exactly what we would expect. Now deselect one of the categories in the legend and you will see the graph move.

How do I stop this from happening? I know it is the [center](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-graph.center) that changes, while the [zoom](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-graph.zoom) stays at the scaleLimit. Is there anything I could do to stop the center from changing, when the scaleLimit is reached?

---

*EDIT:*
I tried this (very hacky) method and it kinda works, still jumps around sometimes, but not as much:

on [graphroam](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.graphroam) event, I set the center like so:

```
let lastCenter = [500, 500]
function handleRoam(evt) {
  const customOptions = chart.value.getOption()

  let newOptionValues = {
    series: {
      center: lastCenter
    }
  }

  if (evt.zoom) {
    if (customOptions.series[0].zoom <= 1) {
      chart.value.setOption(newOptionValues)
    } else if (customOptions.series[0].zoom > 1 && customOptions.series[0].zoom < 10) {
      lastCenter = customOptions.series[0].center
    } else if (customOptions.series[0].zoom >= 10) {
      chart.value.setOption(newOptionValues)
    }
  } else {
    lastCenter = customOptions.series[0].center
  }
}
```

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a similar hacky solution which doesnt jump as far as I can see but drifts a bit when hitting the scaleLimit.
[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=graph-label-overlap&code=LYTwwgFghgTgLgOgM4QPYHcAyqoBMCWAdgOYAUAlANwBQAJAsQKZwBSAygPIBypAShxwAqAfQAKAQUEAJAAQBqGQHIA9LihwoyqEiTNV6zQBtGSALTB8umFABGxpAgBWSVIUUAaGQDMAroQDGcPiuMqTE1gAOEOQyAN7UMjKgkLCIEPi4jNh4RGRUCTKoEUEhALxxBYlwqKiGQREAXHEAvu6VMsZMhLhNANrtifGJw8NqGk3hUFEI_uqMxKgw-CYIwFOkvgElhKFQMUMjhzDMPjA7UAiEUMCMNIfDzeQDMs3tALptI1bLSH3PB_crjcmopMCYZABZSyMax2EweZ5VEARRggyZRBH3RKGKAgVA-OAgwiuRiYrFjKATSIQS6oTJIT5YwxEADWvxk6JpzMIbMZ91mcHmix-VKmNIFQqWJj5RxwwCacBgPkYMpGOJsjEMTQBWJQGAVSpViOGEVQSHw2xBS2IEDgZKx3kWazggpgINiNmaimNrWN6s1mFx-MJFQdiXSmQ4ADcYTjGjJFcqfarhkhZsZMPgLCGdfcLIQmgAGBAAFhTIzWAA8mgAmZN-oiMNhwEDGbXGxL-WqLEEuU7-Unl4b-U4xwgmdnFgDMPuerxGbwKzTuSXA0HgyGYHGKwUIpCK23yjxo1GMcBkA8Irpk5V6bxoZ4vp2OV7Y6cYN5kAEYaMl14hXFIRRORgOUPG8PxAl3UgIlga4kH2Ap8C8UJYOsYAHAALxqYBEJGEcYBfOA3ygYwZAAKnKND4IQbDUGAFcRmQ0ICKIkiyIAPnKGs8KxVjGFfd9PxrRjDj_VJNzgbdtlIWJvhMbVL1dJolJhZpjznGRNV0GRmNIfjBNIj8AB5ymLEteP5Z8BOIoSzNLUSKzXCTdCkndALkmERTiVS3QvGy1I0-5mi0wwdNzYcApgT9xI3Jg3Jk8hNylJBekLN4ZiixyXiXahHiAA):

```js
let center = [];
let currentScale = 1;
myChart.on('graphroam', function(params) {
  if (params.zoom) {
    currentScale *= params.zoom;
      if (currentScale >= 2) {
        currentScale = 2;
        myChart.setOption({series: {center: center}});
      } else if (currentScale <= 0.4) {
        currentScale = 0.4;
        myChart.setOption({series: {center: center}});
      } else {
        center = myChart.getOption().series[0].center;
      }
  }
})
```

Comment: Yep, pretty much the same code, I just get the currentScale from `myChart.getOption().series[0].zoom`

Also I would add an else case to the `if(params.zoom)`, or else you will have problems with dragging (zoom out, drag, zoom out --> graph jumps). 

I wonder if its a bug, since I dont expect the center to move when setting a scaleLimit..

Comment: I am pretty certain that it is a bug. You should open an issue on [github](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues).

Comment: Found an open issue from 1.5 years ago [here](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/17052) , doesnt look like its going to get fixed anytime soon though